# Crossed bell on notification meaning in CM12's Lollipop

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, 5.0-lollipop, notification-icons

I'm using OnePlus One (bacon) running CM12 Unofficial (daleski75's build). If you long-press a notification, you could see a crossed bell on some app.

[image: crossed bell in Lollipop]

It seems to *permanently mute* every notification with the same text inside. A new notification with a different text from the same app is shown as usual.

Is that the meaning of that button? How can re-enable notifications with the same text?

Comment: Looking from the answers, looks like it's not a standard Lollipop feature. Could you please also mention the device model and whether you're using custom ROM or not?

Comment: @AndrewT. OnePlus One (bacon) running CM12 Unofficial (daleski75's build)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android 5.0 (at least in the CM12 Unofficial builds) you can go to Settings -> Privacy

[image: Privacy]

From there go in to Filter Notifications. Clicking on an item will allow you to see when it was last blocked and remove it from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a setting that can be changed under `Settings->Privacy->Filter notifications`.